# zedgraph: how to get dashed lines independant of physical graph size or # of data points

Tags: zedgraph

when i plot my data, the dashes are only visible if: the # of data points is small, or if i manually widen the window, or if i zoom in on the graph. my expectation is that i'd see dashes regardless of these factors, as you'd get in excel. am i overlooking a zedgraph config?  thanks very much.

> ```
>    void plot_array(ref ZedGraphControl zgc)
>    {
>        int num_samples = 100;
>        double[] xvals = new double[num_samples];
>        double[] yvals = new double[num_samples];
>
>        for (double i = 0; i < num_samples; i++)
>        {
>            xvals[(int)i] = i / 10;
>            yvals[(int)i] = Math.Sin(i / 10);
>        }
>
>        var lineItem = zgc.GraphPane.AddCurve("Can't see the dashes", xvals, yvals, Color.Black);
>
>        lineItem.Line.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
>        lineItem.Line.DashOn = 10;
>        lineItem.Line.DashOff = 10;
>        lineItem.Symbol.Type = SymbolType.None;
>
>        zgc.AxisChange();
>        zgc.Refresh();
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious , nothing is wrong with your settings, everything is normal since you have lot of data the dashed line tends to (look) straight line.
if you try:

```
lineItem.Line.DashOn = 1;
lineItem.Line.DashOff = 10;
```

it solves your problem

Comment: thanks for the reply. it worked for that specific example, but it doesn't solve the problem generally. (my actually application would have thousands of points representing sensor data.) i changed the number of samples in my example from 100 to 500, and the numerators in the xval/yval lines from 10 to 50 (as shown above) and the problem recurs. line dashing should be independent of the size of the data or physical size of the graph, but it doesn't appear zedgraph can do it. (?)

Comment: not only zedGraph can't do it but nobody can do it if it is 1000's of points within (small) area, the density would be so high, what i suggest is to make your area wider, for example since you draw data from sensor so your X-axis will be Time[s] right? i suggest you to scroll it, i guess it gives you what you want

Comment: i respectfully disagree.  i can do it in excel.  here is a link to an image that shows perfectly uniform dashing for 500, 5000, and 10000 points in excel. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4fQuM2UwR0Ub1NiQVRJLTdUZGc/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

Comment: here's a link to the excel document if you wish to play with it. download then open in excel 2010: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fQuM2UwR0UU1BPamR4N2Rmd0U/edit?usp=sharing